# Composer use SVN fails - SVN was not found

Tags: svn, symfony, composer-php

I have a Symfony2 project that uses composer to manage packages. I want to add another package from my personal SVN storage. This is my repository configuration in composer.json. I changed my SVN url to now show the real one just for the sake of not showing sensitive information in stackoverflow. I am running on a windows 7 platform. I have installed SVN for windows http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

```
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jquery/jquery",
            "version": "1.9.1",
            "dist": {
                "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",
                "type": "file"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "svn",
        "url": "https://This-is-where-my-path-is"
    }
]
```

When I execute

```
composer --verbose update
```

I get the following result

```
Loading composer repositories with package information



  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to load https://This-is-where-my-path-is, svn was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

  Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet.




Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/SvnDriver.php:316
 Composer\Repository\Vcs\SvnDriver->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repositor
y/Vcs/SvnDriver.php:205
 Composer\Repository\Vcs\SvnDriver->getBranches() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repos
itory/Vcs/SvnDriver.php:75
 Composer\Repository\Vcs\SvnDriver->initialize() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Reposi
tory/VcsRepository.php:78
 Composer\Repository\VcsRepository->getDriver() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Reposit
ory/VcsRepository.php:113
 Composer\Repository\VcsRepository->initialize() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Reposi
tory/ArrayRepository.php:170
 Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository->getPackages() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Dep
endencyResolver/Pool.php:169
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Inst
aller.php:353
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:215
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:12
3
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Sy
mfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/con
sole/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:892
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfon
y/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console
/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfon
y/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/A
pplication.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer.phar:15


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers]
 [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [
packagesN]
```

Now you probably think oh hes not got SVN in the path(since that's the error message I get  in danish)... but I do. Running SVN command gives me

```
Type 'svn help' for usage.
```

So I do have an SVN client running and it is configured in the path.
I even tested running

```
svn checkout https://This-is-where-my-path-is
```

Which works as intended. It checks out my project.
Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I ran this command php composer.phar update -vvv and got this:

```
> C:\xampp\php\php.exe composer.phar update -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
Loading composer repositories with package information
Executing command (CWD): svn ls --verbose --non-interactive "https://This-is-where-my-path-is"
Executing command (CWD): svn --version



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                   
  Failed to load https://This-is-where-my-path-is, svn was not found, check   
  that it is installed and in your PATH env.                                                                           

  Den angivne sti blev ikke fundet.                                                                                    




Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/SvnDriver.php:316
 Composer\Repository\Vcs\SvnDriver->execute() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/SvnDriver.php:205
 Composer\Repository\Vcs\SvnDriver->getBranches() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/SvnDriver.php:75
 Composer\Repository\Vcs\SvnDriver->initialize() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/VcsRepository.php:78
 Composer\Repository\VcsRepository->getDriver() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/VcsRepository.php:113
 Composer\Repository\VcsRepository->initialize() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:170
 Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository->getPackages() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:169
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:353
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:215
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:123
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:892
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/dagtilbudsupport/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\xampp\htdocs\dagtilbudsupport\composer.phar:15


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]



Process finished with exit code 1 at 11:38:44.
Execution time: 1.360 ms.
```

Comment: The `%PATH%` your user account/shell sees is most likely different from the one seen by composer.

Comment: Could be true. But how would I fix that if that is the problem? :|

Comment: Start by finding out if it's true. Then figure out how to get composer's environment variables in line. Alternately, specify the full path to `svn.exe` instead of *hoping* that it falls in the path, thus removing all doubt.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. Composer expects me to write a type "svn" and not a path.. in my PATH in windows7 I have C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin and C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin

Comment: Try `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\svn.exe"` where you would normally put `svn`.

Comment: I'm not allowed to... composer want a type in the "type" field... not a path...

Comment: Somewhere in the configuration of Composer there **must** be a way to tell it where to find the Subversion binaries.

Comment: svn is just called and it's assumed to be in your path, it's easy to trace through in the code but see also https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/564

Comment: Running `composer -vvv update` may give some more useful output?

Comment: I updated the question with the dump from composer -vvv ... not sure if it helps... I'm still not sure whats going wrong...